# regex to match any combination of text of indeterminate length

Tags: linux, regex, grep, sed, awk

A Windows SyncToy logfile contains several thousand lines of the form:

xxx ... C:\zzz.  xxx ...

and

xxx ... zzz\.  xxx ...

where xxx can be a string including any printable character including spaces and/or whitespace

and zzz can be a string including any printable character including spaces, backslashes, numerics, alphas (any case), **.** character, underscore, em-dash, en-dash

Each line will always contain a string zzz. as above,  which may start with the characters C:\ followed by a string of indeterminate length (but let's say with a maximum of 256 chars) and ending with a **.** character; but it may not always start with C:\, it may simply start with some printable characters.

zzz will always start at character (column) 41

As you will recognise, C:\zzz. follows the pattern of an absolute pathname of a file under Windows (7 to be exact) with a trailing **.** character, but not always a terminating backslash.

So a typical line would be:

```
Error: Cannot read from the source file Error: Cannot read from the source file AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-981944830-553675151-235582288-1001\. Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Another would be:

```
Error: Cannot read from the source file C:\Users\zamenhof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_256.db. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) Copying C:\Users\zamenhof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_256.db to G:\gc\Users\zamenhof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_256.db
```

My requirement is to extract each full pathname from each line. So in the first  example above, my desired output would be

```
AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-981944830-553675151-235582288-1001\.
```

and in the second:

```
C:\Users\zamenhof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_256.db.
```

Clearly I can cut the first 40 characters off each line, but this nevertheless leaves me with a string to match which is of indeterminate length, and may contain any or all of  spaces, alphanumerics, **.** characters, underscores and backslashes.

I am familiar with simple regexes but I can't find a way to construct the ones I need to use grep (or sed or awk or whatever the most appropriate tool is) to extract the strings I want.

The files will come from Win7 but will probably get manipulated in Linux. Extended regex tools are available.

If there is an easier way to handle this than using Linux text tools and regex I'll be happy to follow that up too.

Comment: (1) Your problem is ambiguously defined.  I don't see anything in your question that prevents the error messages (`Access is denied.` and `The process cannot access the file …`) from being part of zzz, since it is allowed to contain spaces. (2) Your first example seems to be garbled; it says `Error: Cannot read from the source file` twice, so the filename (`AppData\…`) starts at column 81.  … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-Man I find the question quite understandable, although it definitely could be clearer and better defined.

Comment: @simlev: OK; can you explain why the desired output (which, I guess, is “zzz”, although the question doesn’t say so) for the second example can’t be `C:\Users\zamenhof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_256.db. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`?  What prevents `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` from being part of “zzz”?

Comment: @G-Man I'm not arguing with you, I too see inconsistencies in the explanation but I think the message more or less comes through, thanks mainly to the examples which nail the starting point and the desired output. **Yes, the question should be edited** by the OP, but I think I understand what he means to say.

Answer (score -1):

```
[^\\]* (\S*\\\S*)
```

With this regex, the highlighted parts from the text blow will be captured in the first group.

Error: Cannot read from the source file Error: Cannot read from the source file **AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-981944830-553675151-235582288-1001.** Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Error: Cannot read from the source file **C:\Users\zamenhof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_256.db.** The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) Copying C:\Users\zamenhof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_256.db to G:\gc\Users\zamenhof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_256.db

**Explanation:** (more or less copy/pasted form regex101.com)

```
[^\\]* Match zero or more characters, excluding the backslash
\\ matches the character \ literally
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible

(space) matches the character (space) literally

1st Capturing Group (\S*\\\S*)
\S* matches any non-whitespace character
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
\\ matches the character \ literally
\S* matches any non-whitespace character
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
```

**Learn:** To experiment with regular expressions, you can take advantage of websites such as [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) or [regexr.com](http://regexr.com).

**Tools:** You don't mention which tools you are going to use, but here's a `perl` example:

```
perl -lane 'print $1 if /[^\\]* (\S*\\\S*)/' file.txt
```

Comment: OK, this solution works *for **the examples*** in the question.  The results for `Encountered input\output error on file  Appdata\Roaming\foo\. blah blah blah` (since “xxx” can contain backslashes) or `blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah C:\Program Files\foo. blah blah blah` (since “zzz” can contain spaces) are probably not useful.  Let me know if the OP fixes the question to make your answer correct.